# Inserting time and date using Datetimepicker

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm building an application with C# code.
This is a simple code for inserting values unto the database. I have successfully inserted the values but when I checked on the time column where I have used the datetimepicker, it would only show 0000-00-00 00:00:00. So my problem is, How can you insert time and date only into the database?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "Database=fillupform;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=''";

        timeanddate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        timeanddate.CustomFormat = "MM dd yyyy hh mm ss";  timeanddate.Value.ToShortDateString();
        string Query = "Insert into fillupform.fillupform (filename,instructor,time,score) values('" + this.filename.Text + "','" + this.instructor.Text + "','" + this.timeanddate.Text + "','" + this.score.Text + "');";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
                MessageBox.Show("Saved");
            while (myReader.Read())
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: For the love of god use parameterized SQL otherwise you're opening up yourself to SQL injection attacks!

Comment: @Lloyd I am starting a simple one and once I've got this problem working, I'll start to work on the security. Thanks for the tip sir.

Comment: It would also help resolve this issue as you won't have to worry about the format of the date/time string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to use a `MySqlDataReader`

```
string constring = "Database=fillupform;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=''";
string Query = "INSERT INTO fillupform.fillupform (filename,instructor,time,score) VALUES (@filename,@instructor,@time, @score);";
using (MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase))
    {
        cmdDatabase.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", this.filename.Text);
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@instructor", this.instructor.Text);
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", this.timeanddate.Text);
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", this.score.Text);
        try
        {
            cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for checking this out sir. I tried your solution but it give me an error on this line that goes "no overload method 'cmdDatabase.EndExecuteNonQuery();' takes 0 arguments. Can you help me with this sir?

Comment: @helpmeplease - updated. ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of inserted rows

Comment: I've replace the ones you've updated and added conDataBase.Open and now it works, but I still can't see the date and time inserted on the database, still gives me 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: set a breakpoint and look into this.timeanddate.Text's value - is there a valid value?

Comment: To solve this problem, I've just change the type of the time column on the database into varchar. Now the time and date from the picker are now entered. Thanks for you time sir!